# Test if I have too many TempDB Files

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I know there are ways to test for tempdb contention to see if you need to add more tempdb files, but how can I test (and maybe prove) if I have *too many* tempdb files?

I've inherited a relatively large SQL Server (36CPU, 428GB RAM) that has 24 tempdb files.  I feel like this may be a part of the performance issues we are having, but I don't know how to prove that there are too many.

I know what [the recommendations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2154845/recommendations-to-reduce-allocation-contention-in-sql-server-tempdb-d) are, but somewhere along the way, a DBA before me added them to "improve performance," and I'm in a situation where I can't reduce the number or make changes to the number of files without showing that there is a need.  Saying that it's Microsoft's recommendation isn't good enough this time, unfortunately.

Comment: Interesting read: https://forrestmcdaniel.com/2018/09/28/too-many-tempdb-datafiles/

Comment: **The recommendation is 1 file per core is quite outdated.** Most modern recommendations are to start with 4 or 8 and increase in 4s if you see contention.

Comment: *this may be a part of the performance issues we are having* - describe the issues. Why do you think they are related to tempdb files count?